# Delete a template function except its one specialization

Tags: c++, c++17

Instead of deleting specializations, sometimes, it is more convenient
delete the template function itself but for one of its specializations.

An example:

```
template<typename T>
bool IsLucky(T) = delete;


bool IsLucky<int>(int n) {
return !(n%7);
}
// I guess bool IsLucky(int n) will not help my cause
```

With the help of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), here, I can guarantee that no implicit conversions happen without using the angle brackets.

```
char c='F';
IsLucky(c); // Will not compile
```

Is there any downside to this approach?

Comment: So you can't use SFINAE? `std::enable_if<std::is_same<int , T> ...` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you. I'll have a look at that.

Comment: "Is there any downside to this approach?" That might be too broad ...  By now I cannot think of any, TBH.  And SFINAE gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Plain function overloading works pretty well here:

```
template<typename T>
bool IsLucky(T) = delete;

inline bool IsLucky(int n) {
    return !(n%7);
}

int main() {
    IsLucky(1);
    IsLucky(1u);  // error: use of deleted function ‘bool IsLucky(T) [with T = unsigned int]’
    IsLucky('1'); // error: use of deleted function ‘bool IsLucky(T) [with T = char]’
}
```

---

As a side note, from compiling times perspective, [SFINAE may slow down compilation times considerably](https://youtu.be/NPWQ7xKfIHQ?t=1042).

Comment: Thank you for your time. I insisted on template specialization because it is more explicit and gives the user a clear picture of what is going on without costing anything at runtime. The specialized version too can be inlined. So how is plain function overloading better here?

Comment: @sjsam I won't use a template when a plain function suffices. I am a user and it is clear to me what is going on. Full template specialization requires more effort to type, more effort to read and an extra effort to ponder upon why would the author not use a plain function here.